# LINQ context refresh bug

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2012-express

I have LINQ to SQL classes and a `DataGrid` control. I set the `DataSource` of the `DataGrid` to `context.Users` and then I add user using `context.Users.InsertOnSubmit()`. However, `DataGrid` does not refresh itself, even after calling `Refresh()` explicitly. The only solution is to recreate the context.

I have worked with LINQ to SQL and never had this issue. Now I have **SQL server express 2012 and VS 2012**, I have used to work with 2010. Is this a known bug?

```
    DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = context.Uzivatels;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        context.Uzivatels.InsertOnSubmit(new Uzivatel() { Jmeno = "fdasfsa", Prijmeni = "fdfwe", Pohlavi = "m", Mesto_ID = 1 });
        context.SubmitChanges();

        dataGridView1.Refresh();
        // after this it will add row to database but not to dataGridView

    }
```

Comment: can you post your code sniplet? I'm sure your problem is in your code.

Comment: I've added code. Just simply create context and add record then refresh dataGridView. It just add row to database but not to dataGridView.